# I want to change the Post Type slug of a CPT (custom post type) to the category slug of the page

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I have tried this:

```php
function change_cpt_permalink_using_category_slug( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'your_custom_post_type_name' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            $permalink = str_replace( '%category%', $terms[0]->slug, $permalink );
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'change_cpt_permalink_using_category_slug', 10, 2 );
```

It works but I realized that all my normal Wordpress default post now returns a 404 page

I have also tried this to modify the rewrite argument for the default post type (i.e., post) to exclude the %category% tag:

```php
function remove_category_slug_from_post_permalink( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'post' ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $args['rewrite']['slug'];
        $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'remove_category_slug_from_post_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: can you describe what you want with examples? Your title isn't very clear and the question immediately jumps into the code without clearing up what it is you actually want to do. Note that `post_link` doesn't change the URL of a post, it's only used when displaying the HTML on the frontend, and has nothing to do with processing of page requests or incoming URLs. Think of it as an opportunity to change the address written on a letter, it doesn't change the place you live, only the text written so the letter won't be delivered

Comment: are you asking how to remove the `cpt` part in `/cpt/my-post-slug`? Where is your CPT registration code? And where did you put the 2 code snippets in your question? `functions.php`?

Comment: Yes, remove the cpt part and replace with the slug of that post category. instead of cpt/my-blog-post , it should be my-category-slug/my-blog-post